# How to detect that the user is logged out to notify before redirecting to sign in

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

Add next-auth to the application to authenticate with the AzureADProvider. It's a one page app for now, so I'm not using any navigation.

I would like to add an info popup for the user when the session expired, before redirecting to the sign in page.

I'm using this versions: "next": "14.1.0" and "next-auth": "4.24.6"

I also added refetchInterval={n} in SessionProvider to check the session state every n seconds. That allows me to update the state, otherwise I would have to change the tab or reload the page to get the current state.

if I use status to get the state is not authenticated, I can only make an alert, but if I change a local state to show some modal popup, the library redirects.

```
  const { status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
      alert('session ends');
      setTimeOutSession(true); 
    }
  }, [status]);
```

Can I somehow stop the redirect and just accept the popup and redirect manually?
I think I have to modify some configuration of the AuthOptions, but I don't know which one

My current configuration:

```
const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID ,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: 'email' },
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 20, // just for testing this
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: parseInt(process.env.JWT_MAX_AGE_SECONDS),
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
};
```